# Rails JS delegation event triggering on load?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I am trying to remove some value from session on click, but It seems like It gets triggered without clicking ( on reload ).

This is my code (coffee + erb):

```
  $(document).on "click", ".top-bar[data-chatbox-id='<%=chat.id%>'] .fa-times", (e) ->
    $box_position = $("div.chat_box[data-chatbox-id='<%=chat.id%>']").position().left
    $("div.chat_box[data-chatbox-id='<%=chat.id%>']").remove()

    ## ################### LINE BELOW IS THE ONE CAUSING PROBLEMS #######
    <% session[:chatrooms].delete(chat.id) %>

    chats = $('.chat_box')
    chats.each (index, element) =>
      if $(element).position().left < $box_position
        $(element).css( 'right', '-=' + 310 + 'px' )
```

After reloading session seems to get cleared - shouldn't it be triggered only on a click?

The only thing that comes to my mind is that: "If the selector is null or omitted, the event is always triggered when it reaches the selected element.", but I create the selected element earlier using:

```
$(document.body).append("<%= j render '/chatrooms/chatroom' %>")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because you are evaluating the session deletion in runtime and that's not what you wanna. You want to execute the deletion on click event.

In order to do that you can perform an Ajax request on click which calls the session deletion in a controller level.